# Programmatic editing of XML files

Tags: xml

I'm looking for a way to edit XML files programatically, with edits made to certain nodes depending on the values of their parent/child nodes. Below is an excerpt from one such file, the  tag would typically be repeated hundreds of times. I'd like to be able to manipulate these files fairly generally, but to start with there are 2 examples that i need to achieve right now:

1) Set all the  tags and set their value equal to the  tag of the parent  tag. So in the example below would be changed to Perim West_RM000001

2) Change the / value to a different value but only if / matches a value from a list.

So far I have simply been making these changes manually (copy/paste) but will need to make similar changes regularly so would like to automate the process.

I have limited experience in C++ and Python, or would be happy to use an existing application if something is capable of achieving this.

```
<Spc>
  <Name>Perim West_RM000001</Name>
  <CondgType>DirectlyConditioned</CondgType>
  <SupPlenumSpcRef>- none -</SupPlenumSpcRef>
  <RetPlenumSpcRef>- none -</RetPlenumSpcRef>
  <ThrmlZnRef>Zn Perim West</ThrmlZnRef>
  <IntWall>
    <Name>RM000001_W40</Name>
    <Status>New</Status>
    <AdjacentSpcRef>Perim South_RM000004</AdjacentSpcRef>
    <ConsAssmRef>2013 Internal Partition</ConsAssmRef>

  </IntWall>
  <ExtWall>
    <Name>RM000001_W12</Name>
    <Status>New</Status>
    <ConsAssmRef>2013 External Wall</ConsAssmRef>
    <Win>
      <Name>RM000001_W1-W0</Name>
      <Status>New</Status>
      <FenConsRef>2013 External Window</FenConsRef>
    </Win>
 </Spc>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) and an XSLT processor.  Be aware, however, that the XSLT language can take some effort to get your head around.  It is *very* different from languages such as C++ and Python.

Comment: you should give a try to c# , .net has got so many good stuffs for xml editing